# Unable to Install Watir after installing Ruby

Tags: ruby, watir

I installed  ruby186-26.exe available on ruby forge on my system and then successfully executed the following commands

```
gem install rubygems-update-1.3.7.gem
gem env
gem install activesupport --version="2.3.8"
```

but after this i am not able to install watir and getting this error

```
C:\Users\mayurpandey\Desktop>gem install watir
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
        commonwatir requires user-choices (>= 0, runtime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Ruby 1.8.7  the most recent versions of watir are known to work with it.

Or you can use Watir-Webdriver and a recent ruby 1.9 version as described by Zeljko in his instruction.  (Watir-Webdriver uses the Selenium webdriver back-end to drive the browser and thus has wider browser support including chrome, headless, newer versions of FireFox, and Opera(I'm told, not sure if anyone has tested that)

Comment: watir-webdriver can drive IE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera (tested) and maybe even Chromium (not tested).

Comment: Thanx a lot ... i successfully installed ruby 1.9 and was able to install watir.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you follow this instructions to install Watir (My guess is that you are on Windows 7): https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows-7.md

There is a pdf version here: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Disclaimer: I am the author of the instructions.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I was able to install watir using the above instructions. And you got it right, I am using windows 7.

Comment: @Mayur,  You should accept one of the answers, and upvote on any that helped you.  That rewards the people who assisted you by boosting their reputation, and lets someone else with the same issue easily identify the 'best' answer to the question